# Why doesn't the diamond operator work within a addAll() call in Java 7?

Tags: java, generics, java-7, diamond-operator

Given this example from [the generics tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html#type-inference-instantiation).

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("A");

// The following statement should fail since addAll expects
// Collection<? extends String>

list.addAll(new ArrayList<>());
```

Why does the last line not compile, when it seems it should compile. The first line uses a very similar construct and compiles without a problem.

Please explain elaborately.

Comment: "Why doesn't the following does not work?" is a bit weak. What exactly do you expect? And what is the error message? There are many reasons "it does not work". You should be more precise in your question to get precise answers.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html come back when you've read and absorbed that.

Comment: I vote to reopen the question, because (contrary to many other such questions), it's about the diamond operator, which I'd guess is **not yet** extensively covered on SO.

Comment: I extremley agree with Joachim Sauer.Ya i agree this a direct copy from the tutorial...I cound not understand it there.So i asked it here.Please Help me....

Comment: Actually, as of Java 7 this should work - `diamond operator`, voting for reopen, too.

Comment: @Thomas: no, it shouldn't. The diamond operator does not work in this case. And *why* it doesn't work is actually non-trivial. That's why I think this question should be reopened.

Comment: @Matt Ball and others.Please reopen the question and allow it to be discussed...or can you explain it to me elaboratly

Comment: Pradeep, are you using Java 7? That's a prerequisite for that to compile.

Comment: Hi thomas...I am not using Java7.I was reading the java tutorial.So i wanted to know why that code would not compile....Can you explain me..I am a beginner..

Comment: @PradeepKumar: if you're **not** using Java 7, then **that** is the reason why your code doesn't compile: The tutorial is targeted at Java 7. *However* the specific code you quote doesn't even compile on Java 7 (for other reasons).

Comment: @Pradeep we'll explain that once the question is reopend, otherwise future readers might not see the exlanation in the comments.

Comment: I am not actually running this code in java 7.I read that code somewhere ,and just wanted to know why it won't work?

Comment: @Thomas.How can we reopen the question?

Comment: You can't but I just voted for it as well so we only need one more vote :) While I don't really see any good use case for it, I'm not sure why it shouldn't work, apart from "Rarely used and not worth the additional complexity"

Comment: 5 votes to close, 5 to reopen a question - we're at 4 atm

Comment: Actually is an interesting question. Why inference works with the left operand in assignments but not with method calls.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, ah good point. I wasn't aware of the `<>` operator... WOuldn't have voted to close. Ah well, it's opened already!

Answer (score 14):

First of all: unless you're using Java 7 all of this will not work, because [the diamond `<>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html#type-inference-instantiation) has only been introduced in that Java version.

Also, this answer assumes that the reader [understands the basics of generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). If you don't, then read *the other parts* of the tutorial and come back when you understand those.

The diamond is actually a shortcut for not having to repeat the generic type information when the compiler could find out the type on its own.

The most common use case is when a variable is defined in the same line it's initialized:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // is a shortcut for
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In this example the difference isn't major, but once you get to `Map<String, ThreadLocal<Collection<Map<String,String>>>>` it'll be a **major** enhancement (note: I **don't** encourage actually using such constructs!).

The problem is that the rules only go that far. In the example above it's pretty obvious what type should be used and both the compiler and the developer agree.

On this line:

```
list.addAll(new ArrayList<>());
```

it *seems* to be obvious. At least the developer knows that the type should be `String`.

However, looking at the definition of [`Collection.addAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) we see the parameter type to be `Collection<? extends E>`.

It means that `addAll` accepts any collection that contains objects of any unknown type that extends the type of our `list`. That's good because it means you can `addAll` a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Number>`, but it makes our type inference trickier.

In fact it makes the type-inference not work within the rules currently laid out by the JLS. In *some* situations it could be argued that the rules *could* be extended to work, but the current rules imply don't do it.

Comment: @joachim.Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

The explanation from the [Type Inference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html#type-inference-instantiation) documentation seems to answer this question directly ( unless I'm missing something else ).

Java SE 7 and later support limited type inference for generic instance creation; you can only use type inference if the parameterized type of the constructor is obvious from the context. For example, the following example does not compile:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("A");

  // The following statement should fail since addAll expects
  // Collection<? extends String>

list.addAll(new ArrayList<>());
```

Note that the diamond often works in method calls; **however, for greater clarity, it is suggested that you use the diamond primarily to initialize a variable where it is declared**.

In comparison, the following example compiles:

```
// The following statements compile:

List<? extends String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(list2);
```

Comment: The tutorial doesn't really explain **why** the diamond doesn't work here. It just hand-waves and says that it "often works".

Comment: @Kal.Sorry to annoy you.I dint understand .Can you explain it in simple words.Sorry once again

Comment: Agree. Perhaps the JLS says something.

Comment: Hmm.. It seems obvious to me. It clearly states that addAll expects Collection<? extends E> which you can't do because it could be an unknown type extending the defined type of the list and hence inference won't work.

Comment: @Pradeep -- because of the method definition of addAll(), using the diamond operator in your specific example is not enough information to figure out what type to infer the ArrayList as -- since it could be any subclass of your type ( or your type ).

Comment: @Kal: it can easily be argued that in this case it *could* simply infer the type `String` which would be correct according to the type system and which would successfully allow the call. In my opinion that's sufficient. It seems to be a restriction similar to the old "Why doesn't object instantiation use the same inference rules that are used on method invocation?" in Java 5 and Java 6 (still true in Java 7 as well).

Comment: @Joachim -- Thanks. Object instantiation probably does use the same inference rules where possible, right? For example -- `List<ArrayList<String>> aList = new List<>(); aList.add(new ArrayList<>);` should work (dont have java 7 installed, so can't verify).

Comment: @Kal.Here how does the list.addAll(list2); work.Here alse we are not specifying the type of arraylist.

Comment: @PRadeep -- This goes back to what Joachim was saying. The diamond operator is able to infer the type from the constructor definition.

Comment: As Joachim Sauer says, it should be possible to infer the type String. So it seems strange why it isn't done here.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling a method invocation, javac needs to know the type of the arguments first, before determining which method signature matches them. So the method parameter type isn't known before the argument type is known.

Maybe this can be improved; as of today, the type of the argument is independent of the context.