# Java 7 Diamond Operation in method call

Tags: java, java-7, diamond-operator

This is kind of a follow up question on the discussion:

[Why doesn't the diamond operator work within a addAll() call in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555652/why-doesnt-the-diamond-operator-work-within-a-addall-call-in-java-7)

From the Java Tutorial,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html

> Note that the diamond often works in method calls; however, for greater clarity, it is suggested that you use the diamond primarily to initialize a variable where it is declared

So, I am a bit confused about the first line. When **does** diamond work in method calls?

A bit more explanation on how diamond operator works can be found here:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20type%20argument%20inference%20for%20constructors?

And from this, I have tried the following, which works fine:

Give that I have:

```
private static class Box<T>{
    public Box(T t){}
}
static void f(Box<Integer> box){}
```

a call like the following compiles fine:

```
f(new Box<>(new Integer(10)));
```

The type parameter in invoking the constructor in the method call of `f()` above is inferred from the argument to the constructor (i.e. `Integer`).

So is this what is meant when the tutorial says

> Note that the diamond often works in method calls

If not, can anyone kind enough to provide an example where diamond **works** in method call?

Comment: @gurung its a typo. Bad case of cut and paste :(

Answer (score 3):

> So is this what is meant when the tutorial says

I think yes though there are a couple of gotchas when it comes to `<>` operators.

In your case, Box instantiation is a non-issue given that the type can be trivially inferred using the constructor argument. Try changing the constructor to "not" take in an `Integer` or `T` and see how the invocation fails.

```
class BadBox<T> {

    private T t;

    public BadBox(){}    

    public void setT(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    static void f(BadBox<Integer> box){}

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        f(new BadBox<>());  //fails, should have worked ideally
    }    
}
```

Similarly, have a look at this class:

```
class Testi<R> {    
    public void doIt(Set<? extends R> sets) {
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
            // works since type inference is now possible
        new Testi<CharSequence>().doIt(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a")));

            // fails; nothing which can help with type inference
        new Testi<CharSequence>().doIt(new HashSet<>();
    }       
}
```

Similarly, the problem in your linked question (regarding `addAll`) can be simply solved by helping out the compiler a bit as follows:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("A");

// works now! use only if you love diamond operator ;)
list.addAll(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[0])));
// or the old-school way
list.addAll(new ArrayList<String>()));
```

Diamond operators also seem to break when it comes to implementing anonymous classes as follows:

```
final String[] strings = { "a", "b", "c" };
Arrays.sort(strings, new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Fortunately, in this case, the compiler is pretty explicit in mentioning that `<>` doesn't/won't work with anonymous classes.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think that it is worth thinking about when it works and when not. The compiler will tell you and thus you have to rewrite what’s not working.

There is not a real rationale behind it; it’s more like the developers have put the current limitations of the actual compiler’s implementation at a specific time into the specification and told us: that’s how it has to be.

Java 8 lifts a lot of these limitations without the hell freezing over. E.g.

```
Arrays.asList("foo", "bar").addAll(new ArrayList<>());
```

compiles with Java 8 without any error. And, why not?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really about method invocation. The standalone statement

```
new Box<>(new Integer(10));
```

also compiles. There are enough information to infer `T` for `Box` (i.e. from the Integer argument)

On the other hand, this doesn't compile

```
new ArrayList<>();
```

There's no way to know what kind of list is desired.

```
Collection<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

this works because inference is helped by the target type `Collection<String>`

Comment: `new ArrayList<>();` as a stand-alone statement *does* compile.