# Error while creating LinkedList of LInkedLists

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to create a LinkedList of LinkedLists in Java.

The following code segment is giving an error. I am using java 11 and util.List

No idea why I am getting this error..

```
N = in.read();
List<List<Integer>> L;
L = new LinkedList<>();
for( i = 0;i<N;i++) L.add(new LinkedList<>());
```

It gives the following errors:

```
A.java:25: error: cannot infer type arguments for LinkedList
            L = new LinkedList<>();
                              ^
  reason: cannot use '<>' with non-generic class LinkedList
A.java:26: error: cannot infer type arguments for LinkedList
            for( i = 0;i<N;i++) L.add(new LinkedList<>());
                                                    ^
  reason: cannot use '<>' with non-generic class LinkedList
```

How should I go on resolving this?

---

Okay, so just to test I created a dummy class just to create  LinkedList of LinkedLists. Here is the full program:

```
import java.util.*;
class Dummy
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<List<Integer>> L;
        L = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) L.add(new LinkedList<>());    
    }
}
```

Again, these errors:

```
A.java:7: error: cannot infer type arguments for LinkedList
        L = new LinkedList<>();
                          ^
  reason: cannot use '<>' with non-generic class LinkedList
A.java:8: error: cannot infer type arguments for LinkedList
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) L.add(new LinkedList<>());    
                                                    ^
  reason: cannot use '<>' with non-generic class LinkedList
```

Edit: Okay, works fine when I use import java.util.List and import java.util.linkedList instead of import java.util.*

As pointed out in the comments there is probably some issue with my build path

Comment: Have you named one of your classes `LinkedList`, by any chance?

Comment: Works fine for me with java11

Comment: @kaya3 No I haven't

Comment: Show your actual imports and the type signature of the class you're running this from. That it says `LinkedList` isn't generic is a big warning flag.

Comment: Add complete code.

Comment: @NawnitSen added full code

Comment: Do you have a class named `LinkedList` in the same package as class `Dummy`? Or another class in file A.java named `LinkedList`?

Comment: @DaveNewton did

Comment: @TedHopp no, I don't. The only package I am importing is util.*

Comment: Try importing `java.util.LinkedList` (and `java.util.List`) explicitly, rather than using a wildcard `import` statement. Since `java.util.LinkedList` is a generic class, the compiler is definitely picking up some non-generic class `LinkedList` from somewhere.

Comment: I see no issue with this.Works fine for me in eclipse. Check your build path for correct java version or project facet once.

Comment: @TedHopp wow works fine when I do that, why is it so? edit: ok, got it

Comment: You probably have a (non-generic) class `LinkedList` somewhere that the compiler is looking. It may only be a left-over `.class` file. Try cleaning out your build artifacts.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637581/java-7-diamond-operation-in-method-call

Comment: Check your other dependencies or class within your code in same package, if you have any other class name as LinkedList. This class might not be generic which might be causing issues. 
It works fine for me with Java8 and Java 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your example using java7 and using java8, and it gives me the same error as you are seeing for java7, but works for me for java8.

Why it doesn't work for java7 will have to do with limitations of type inference in that version of the compiler.

I would expect java11 to work at least as well as java8 (which is to say, the code should compile using java11).  Can you double check your compiler settings?  You may be using a java11 compiler, but may have set it to generate code using the java7 rules.

Here is the version of the code that I tested:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TypeTest {
    private static final int STORAGE_SIZE = 10;

    private static final List<List<Integer>> storage = new LinkedList<>();

    static {
        for ( int elementNo = 0; elementNo < STORAGE_SIZE; elementNo++ ) {
            storage.add( new LinkedList<>() );
        }
    }
}
```