# Java type inference not working as I expect

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I've got this method (this is a simplification of my original problem):

```
public List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, List<?>>> method(List<?> list) {
    return Collections.singletonList(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("", list));
}
```

However, this results in a compile error:

> ```
> Console.java:40: error: incompatible types
>         return Collections.singletonList(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("", list));
>                                         ^
>   required: List<SimpleEntry<String,List<?>>>
>   found:    List<SimpleEntry<String,List<CAP#1>>>
>   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>     CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
> 10 errors
> ```

If I try to specify the type instantiation on the top-level method:

```
return Collections.<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, List<?>>>singletonList(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("", list));
```

I get a different error:

> ```
> Console.java:40: error: method singletonList in class Collections cannot be applied to given types;
> return Collections.<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, List<?>>>singletonList(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("", list));
>                   ^
>   required: T
>   found: SimpleEntry<String,List<CAP#1>>
>   reason: actual argument SimpleEntry<String,List<CAP#1>> cannot be converted to SimpleEntry<String,List<?>> by method invocation conversion
>   where T is a type-variable:
>     T extends Object declared in method <T>singletonList(T)
>   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>     CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
> 10 errors
> ```

Only when I specify the type parameters on the *inner* method, does it all work:

```
return Collections.singletonList(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, List<?>>("", list));
```

I don't even pretend to understand what's going on here. I suspect this has something to do with [capture conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) (related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294227/inferred-wildcard-generics-in-return-type)), but I have no idea why specifying the generics on the outer method doesn't work, but on the inner method does. Doesn't java use the return type to infer type arguments for nested calls like this? What's going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the diamond operator work within a addAll() call in Java 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555652/why-doesnt-the-diamond-operator-work-within-a-addall-call-in-java-7)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I originally encountered this problem using just method calls, not constructors. Since the same inference logic is used for methods and constructors with `<>`, I substituted it as a pure-JDK version that replicated the original issue. This question is also primarily about the differences in placement of the explicit type declarations, rather than it inferring anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can not instanciate any class with a wildcard typeparameter (eg. `new ArrayList<?>();` wont compile). So the compiler tries to deduce an existing class for CAP#1, which is impossible since a Wildcard is expected.

The solution is to avoid wildcards. Add a Type parameter to the Method itself like this.

```
public <T> List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, List<T>>> method(List<T> list) {
    return Collections.singletonList(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("", list));
}
```

In addition to the compiler shutting up the signature gets clearer on what realy will be returned from the method.

Comment: I'm not instantiating a wildcard directly, the wildcard is nested (`new ArrayList<List<?>>()` does compile), which is allowed.

Comment: Also, in my actual source code, the wildcard type is being returned from a method call, so I can't get rid of it easily.

Comment: -1 Nested wildcards don't capture. You're changing the behavior of the method with the nested type parameter.

Comment: @PaulBellora you are right. It seems as if the dimond operator is completely unable to deduce a type from a surounding method call.
`f(new ArrayList<>())` with `void f(ArrayList<String> l){}` wont compile.